# How does computer sleep mode works? How RAM holds information even if power is cut off in sleep mode?

Tags: memory, python, virtualization, c#, development

How does computer sleep mode works? How RAM holds information even if power is cut off in sleep mode? RAM is volatile memory which erases everything when power is cut off but if i put my computer to sleep and shut down power it holds all the information when it turns on again.How RAM maintains its state during sleep mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Power to RAM *isn't* cut off in regular sleep mode. If it is, the data is lost.

However, there are several possible modes that could be called 'sleep':

- In traditional S3 "Suspend-to-RAM" sleep mode, everything is powered off *except* the RAM. If you cut the power supply, RAM contents are lost.
- In hibernation mode everything is powered off, *but* the RAM contents are stored to disk (e.g. Windows puts them in a file "hiberfil.sys") before powering off, and are read back during power-on (resume).
- In the "hybrid sleep" mode, the RAM contents are first stored to disk (as if hibernating), but then the computer goes into regular S3 sleep mode (leaving the RAM powered on).

When you click "Sleep" in Windows, many desktops (and occassionally laptops) are configured to use the **hybrid sleep** mode – which means they keep the RAM powered, but also store its contents on disk while going to sleep. So as long as the computer has power, it'll keep RAM contents in place; but if you lose power, it'll simply read the same RAM contents from the hibernation file on disk. With modern fast HDDs you hardly notice the difference.

Comment: Thanks @grawity , is it possible to read "hiberfil.sys" file using any programming language?

Comment: You can read it (subject to permissions) but its contents are not easy to interpret. For one thing it's a copy of RAM, and relating this to virtual addresses within processes is going to take a lot of spelunking through the memory management data. Here's an old BlackHat presentation about it: https://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-08/Suiche/BH_US_08_Suiche_Windows_hibernation.pdf

Comment: It's a _compressed_ copy of RAM, and it isn't a 1:1 copy (it skips free areas obviously, but also skips useless things like the page cache). There probably are forensic tools for examining it.